# How do i get wireless working on my very new macbook pro 9.2 using Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: 12.10, wireless, mac

I have been trying to figure out how to get my wireless working. I am new with linux but I do consider myself computer savy. I have tried using the official Ubuntu help for this problem but I get to a dead end. I think my computer's wireless chip is to new for many of the help forums. Also, when using terminal I found that my wireless is a broadcom BMC4331. If someone could help me out with getting my wireless set up I would be very thankful.

When I type `nm-tool` into terminal I get this:

```
NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: eth0  [Wired connection 1] -------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            tg3
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        40:6C:8F:2C:F1:58

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes
    Speed:           100 Mb/s

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         on

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         10.10.50.247
    Prefix:          16 (255.255.0.0)
    Gateway:         10.10.1.1

    DNS:             8.8.8.8
    DNS:             4.2.2.2
```

Answer (score 0):

According to http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/b43 the b43 driver is supported, so just add the firmware it needs (good to run the update too):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
```

Of course, you should uninstall any other drivers you added in any earlier attempts.
I'd suggest using "purge" to ensure getting rid of any configuration files which may be suppressing the b43 driver, e.g.
  sudo apt-get purge AnyPackagesYouAdded.